# Where can I find the hostname of my server in Java Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, hostname

I'm trying to connect two MacBooks using Java network programming, one is a server and the other is a client. In server, I wrote something like

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8008);
```

and then in my client computer I wrote

```
hostname = "Alex";
Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, 8008);
```

where `"Alex"` is the computer name of my server, found in System Preference -> Sharing -> Computer Name, as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKiz6.png). However when I run the script on client I got the following error message:

```
error: Alex
java.net.UnknownHostException: Alex
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:564)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
        at EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:9)
```

It seems that the hostname of my server is not recognized. Then where should I look up the hostname of my server computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Linux system,
add a record in /etc/hosts.
If you are a Windows system,
add a record in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1   Alex
::1             Alex

Comment: I believe 127.0.0.1 refers to localhost, which works if server and client is on the same computer, however in my case server is on a different computer

Comment: not in proper format